# Mesa Drivers AMD ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, 15.04, mesa

I am using the ATI Mobility Radeo HD 5145 gpu on a Satellite l650. wanting to move from Ubuntu 15.04 to 16.04. Do the Mesa drivers have any known issues on this platform?

Comment: this question doesn't have a definitive answer but their are no issues that I know of with the Update,  some issues can arise but most of them are fixable, it's hard to predict even before installing, however if you upgrade and you do get into some issues you can post a question here, we'll be here to help you.

Comment: I guess the only thing I can really do is "test drive" it, is there a specific set of utilities that I can test the frame rate with etc? I tend to just run a ps1 emulator for the framerate test and opengl test since linux is really only for "school work" This does include running a vm of xp for office apps (since we have to use them in class) surprisingly it handles it well

I will inform you guys for a definitive answer after a 2-3 day trial period of running it

Comment: Update: I can now confirm that 16.04 is not good for this AMD GPU, it seems to run ok but it seems a little "broken" I would advise for people to stay on 15.04 with this particular GPU.

Comment: Gave you tried fixing the issue?

Comment: Kind of late but I've been using Google Docs for schoolwork instead of MS Office. When you go to save the file, you have an option to download the file as a docx file.